# Ways to set default value for class attribute without using hasattr

Tags: python-2.7, class, attributes

I have to set attribute for class instance in case if it doesn't exist.
I am using code below to  achieve that:

```
class O(object):
    pass

o = O()
if not hasattr(o, 'some_attr'):
    setattr(o, 'some_attr', None)
print o.some_attr
```

Is there are better way perform such action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes and its instances has own namespace represented by [pre-defined](http://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/courses/python/class/5/#classattrs) `__dict__` attribute which is dictionary, so method [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) could be used instead of `if hasattr -> setattr` flow to add new attribute to  the class instance:

```
class O():
    pass

o = O()
o.__dict__.setdefault('some_attr', None)

print o.some_attr
```

Method sugggested by **@MartijnPieters**:

Also we could access `__dict__` attribute with [**vars**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) function and call `setdefault`  method as in code sample above:

```
vars(o).setdefault('some_attr', None)
print o.some_attr
```

Comment: I'd use `vars(o)` (just like you'd use `len(obj)` and not `obj.__len__()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your suggestion! That's probably preferred way to perform such action )

Comment: Python 3.1: `vars([object])` **Note:** The returned dictionary should not be modified: the effects on the corresponding symbol table are undefined. (https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#vars)